# Tomcat: How to dynamically set keystoreFile and keystorePass at runtime?

Tags: tomcat

Instead of hardcoding a file path in server.xml, is there a way to dynamically set `keystoreFile` at runtime? For my needs, I need to generate the keystore at runtime, and set that to be used by Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you embed Tomcat in your application. Then you have full programmatic control over the entire configuration. Look at the Tomcat unit tests for lots of examples of how to embed Tomcat, including a number using SSL.